# Laravel blade @include with @yield

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is something similar to this possible in Laravel blade?

```
Route::get('blade', function () {
    return view('aMainPage');
});
```

**aMainPage.blade.php**

```
@include('molecules.blocks.banner', ['background'=> '/image.jpeg'])
   <h1>I am included</h1>
@endinclude
```

**/views/molecules/blocks/banner.blade.php**

```
@if($background)
<section class="banner" style="background-image:url('{{$background}}');">
@else
<section class="banner">
@endif
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    @yield() {{- notice @yield here -}}
</section>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image:url('/image.jpeg');">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>I am included</h1>
</section>
```

---

here is what the above currently renders

**Actual Output**

```
 <section class="banner" style="background-image:url('/image.jpeg');">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</section>


    <h1>I am included</h1>
@endinclude
```

Comment: I have but it doesn't work. I'll add the rendered output.

Comment: no such thing as `@endinclude` either make it a section or simply include the partial

Answer (score 5):

Sure possible,

**molecules/blocks/banner.blade.php**

```
@if(isset($background))
  <section class="banner" style="background-image:url('{{$background}}');">
@else
  <section class="banner">
@endif
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      @yield('main_content')
</section>
```

**aMainPage.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>vNull</title>
</head>
<body>
@section('main_content')
    <h1>Woho</h1>
@endsection
@include('molecules.blocks.banner', ['background' => '/image.jpeg'])
</body>
</html>
```

> Secondary Solution

**molecules/blocks/banner.blade.php**

```
@if(isset($background))
  <section class="banner" style="background-image:url('{{$background}}');">
@else
  <section class="banner">
@endif
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      @stack('main_content')
</section>
```

**aMainPage.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>vNull</title>
</head>
<body>
@include('molecules.blocks.banner', ['background' => '/image.jpeg'])
@push('main_content')
    <h1>Woho</h1>
@endpush
</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>vNull</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="banner" style="background-image:url('/image.jpeg');">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>Woho</h1>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @xdevnull, thanks for replying! I've given this a try and it looks promising but what I'm trying to create is a 'reusable component' where I can use it more than once in the same file.  Do you know if this is possible in blade.

Comment: Hey @Jammer  In that case `@include`, `@stack` will do that job. But let the parent render the child, not the opposite as your question because seems hard to follow if u've very large files. See this small example http://laravel.io/bin/6LPyv